# Custom Upcoming Events List for Events Manager Plugin

Tags: meta-query

I'm using [Events Manager](http://wp-events-plugin.com/) plugin.

I want to list upcoming events without widget. (2 event with big thumbnail image, after then 4 event with small thumbnail image.)

Tried this code:

```
<?phpfunction em_mod_custom_events_list(){
    $events = EM_Events::get(array('scope'=>'future','limit'=>10));
    ?>
    <table>
            <tbody>
    <?php
    $start = false;
    $limit = 3;
    $count = 1;
    foreach( $events as $EM_Event ){
                    ?>
                    <?php if ( !$start ) { ?>
                    <tr>
                    <?php $start = true; ?>
                    <?php } ?>
                            <td><?php echo $EM_Event->output("#_EVENTLINK"); ?></td>
                    <?php
                            if ( $count === $limit ){
                                    ?>
                                    </tr>
                                    <?php
                                    $start = false;
                                    $count = 1;
                            }else{
                                    $count++;
                            }
                    ?>
                    <?php
    }
    ?>
            </tbody>
    </table>
    <?php
}
add_shortcode('custom_events_list', 'em_mod_custom_events_list');
```

but I'm taking "Warning: Illegal offset type in isset or empty" error message.

I wrote this query;

```
            <?php
            $args = array(
                    'posts_per_page' => 4,
                    'post_type' => 'event',
                    'offset'        => 2,
                    'meta_query' => array(
                            array(
                                    'key' => 'event_start_date',
                                    'value' => date('d/m/Y'),
                                    'compare' => '>=',
                                    'type' => 'DATE'                        
                            )
                    ),
                    'post_status' => 'publish',
                    'meta_key' => 'event_start_date',
                    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
                    'order' => 'DESC'
            );
        query_posts($args);
        while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
```

I did not get a result..

How can I do it?

Thanks...

///Edit

Tried this code, it works.

```
            <?php
            $events = EM_Events::get(array('scope'=>'future', 'limit'=>6)); 
            foreach( $events as $EM_Event ){
        ?>            
        <div class="tn-small-1 blocky" style="min-height:105px;margin-bottom:0;">
            <a href="<?php echo $EM_Event->output("#_EVENTURL"); ?>"><img src="<?php echo $EM_Event->output("#_EVENTIMAGEURL"); ?>" width="105" height="85" class="lefty"></a>
            <h4 class="lefty" style="width:100%"><?php echo $EM_Event->output("#_EVENTLINK"); ?></h4><br>
            <p class="righty" style="max-width:253px;"><b>Tarih:</b><?php echo $EM_Event->output("#_EVENTDATES"); ?></p>
        </div>  
        <?php } ?>
```